# Weird Erasure in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have the following interface:

```
public interface Translator
{
    public <T, F> T translate(F from, T to, Class<T> clazz); 
}
```

and the following implementation:

```
class TranslatorImpl implements Translator
{
    @Override
    public <T, F> T translate(F from, T to, Class<T> clazz)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

But for the `translate()` method in the `TranslatorImpl` class, Eclipse complains as follows:

> Name clash: The method translate(F, T, Class) of type
>   TranslatorImpl has the same erasure as translate(F, T, Class) of type
>   Translator but does not override it

Update:
When I do a Maven build it builds properly. I use JDK 1.6 update 31. The JDK compliance level in Eclipse is 1.6

How do I overcome this?

Update 2:

Compliance level settings: [image]

Installed JRE: [image]

Update 3: Contents of my `.classpath` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/dbmodel"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/uimodel"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/common"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="MAXIMUS_DEV_DIR/resources/dependencies/java/log4j/log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Update 4: project specific compiler compliance level settings:
[image]

Comment: Works as it should for me. What compiler do you use?

Comment: You don't need the third parameter, unless you are planning to supply null as the second parameter.

Comment: It is Eclipse which is creating the problems. When I do a Maven build it builds properly. I use JDK 1.6 update 31. The JDK compliance level in Eclipse is 1.6

Comment: Since this is Eclipse specific, can you try removing your implementation altogether? This way Eclipse will complain and suggest you what to do

Comment: Works for me no problem. Upgrade to the latest version of Eclipse and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Prior Java 6 @Override annotation was not allowed for implementing interfaces, this is probably what is happenning. You can try removing the annotation and it should work.
To fix properly check source level compliance in eclipse project properties.

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6. Eclipse 3.7. Compiler compliance level: 1.6

Comment: Source or binary? On the project or eclipse wide? Please be very specific as to how you know that complience is 1.6.

Comment: @hgrey... see my update. Please tell me if I am missing anything.

Comment: You show eclipse wide default compliance, check project properties. You can access them via context menu

Comment: It is the same for both. I have not configured project specific settings.

Comment: You probably haven't, but m2e plugin could have. Can you post screenshot of that too? Also can you paste contents of your .classpath file?

Comment: @hgrey... I am not using m2e plugin. And please find my .classpath file's content in my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10083/discussion-between-hgrey-and-swaranga-sarma)